# Recurring observable streams

Tags: rx-java, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactive

I have a stream of observable events that terminate on an event. However, once terminated, I need the stream to start over again from the beginning. A representation of the stream is below:

```
awaitStartEvent()
  .switchMap(value -> awaitSecondEvent(value))
  .subscribe(result -> {
    doSomethingWithResult(result);
    // need to start at awaitStartEvent again here
  }, error -> {
    handleError(error);
    // need to start at awaitStartEvent again here
  }
```

What's a good way to handle this situation?

Comment: did you tried `repeat` operator?

Comment: Doesn't repeat resubscribe to the last observable? i.e. it would resubscribe to awaitSecondEvent instead of start

Comment: `repeat` resubsribes to the whole upstream.

Comment: Oh, I was confusing it with retry, I'll test it out

Comment: Retry is the same, but only re-subscribes in the case of the sequence terminating with an OnError, not an OnComplete.

Answer (score 0):

As per @maxost's comment, use the `Repeat` operator. If you want it to continue in the face of errors too, then you will need to add the `Retry` operator in there too. This is where you would need to put your `handleError` logic as the final subscription wont ever get to see these errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need `repeat` and `retry`, but since you have a `handleError` side-effect in the question, the exception won't be propagated downstream to handle by the `retry` operator.

Here it is using the `do` class of operators.

```
awaitStartEvent()
  .switchMap(value -> awaitSecondEvent(value))
  .doOnNext(result -> { doSomethingWithResult(result); })
  .doOnError(error -> { handleError(error); })
  .repeat()
  .retry()
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awaitStartEvent()
    .switchMap(value -> awaitSecondEvent(value))
    .doOnNext(result -> doSomethingWithResult(result)) //handle result
    .repeat() //resubsribe when onComplete called
    .doOnError(error -> handleError(error)) //handle error
    .retry() //resubscribe when onError called
    .subscribe();
```